# Script to Insert a Checkbox into every cell and assign it to that cell in Excel and returns true false in a specific selected cell

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

I would need additional help to this formula. Once I have entered this script in my excel worksheet the true false returns in the same cell (next) to the checkbox. How do I modify the script so that true false returns for one checkbox for example in cell (AI9) and for the following check boxes in "AI10, NEXT AI11 and so on..

```
Sub AddCheckBoxes()

Dim cb As CheckBox
Dim myRange As Range, cel As Range
Dim wks As Worksheet

Set wks = Sheets("mySheet") 'adjust sheet to your needs

Set myRange = wks.Range("A1:A10") ' adjust range to your needs

For Each cel In myRange

    Set cb = wks.CheckBoxes.Add(cel.Left, cel.Top, 30, 6) 'you can adjust left, top, height, width to your needs


    With cb

        .Caption = ""
        .LinkedCell = cel.Address

    End With

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.LinkedCell = wks.Cells(cel.Row,"AI").Address()
```